# JSP using String to create hyperlink <a href>

Tags: string, jsp, hyperlink

How to use string to create hyperlink with out.print() in JSP?

String [] results link to be displayed in the JSP page.

```
String [] searchResultTitle;
String [] searchResultLinks;


 for(int j=0; j<searchResult.length; j++){
<p>
out.print(searchResultTitle[j].toString()) ;
</p>

//WHAT TO DO HERE???????????
< a href = searchResultLinks[j].toString()> 

out.print(searchResultLinks[j].toString()) ;

</a>

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way,

```
<%!
    String [] searchResultTitle = {"1","2","3"};
    String [] searchResultLinks = {"www.google.com","www.google.com","www.gmail.com"};
%>
<%
    for(int j=0; j<searchResultLinks.length; j++){
%>
<p>
    <%out.print(searchResultTitle[j].toString()) ; %>
</p>
<%
out.println( "<a href =" + searchResultLinks[j].toString() +"> " + searchResultTitle[j].toString() + "</a>");
}%>
```

You can also try as below,

```
<a href = "<%= searchResultLinks[j].toString() %>" > <%= searchResultTitle[j].toString() %> </a>
```

The is a space between '<' and 'a' in creating anchor link. That's y it rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to print it:

```
out.print("< a href = "+searchResultLinks[j].toString()+"> ");
out.print(searchResultLinks[j].toString()) ;
out.print("</a>");
```

By the way, those `<p>` tags should be printed too, or separate them out from Java code using the JSP tags.